# Proving that $f_n$ doesn't converge uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

Given the succesion $f_{n}(x)=x^{2}+\frac{|x|}{n}$. I decided to do the next thing

Let $\epsilon=1$ . Then there is a N $\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq{N}$ we have $|x^{2}+\frac{|x|}{n}-x^{2}|$ < 1. Let us choose $n=N$, and x=n. Then we have $|x^{2}+\frac{|x|}{n}-x^{2}|$=$\frac{n}{n}=1\geq{1}$ so it doesn't converges uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

One way you might clarify your reasoning is to more explicitly identify why if the sequence converges uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$, it must be to the pointwise limit, i.e., to the function $f(x) = x^2$. You likely know this from a theorem, but if it's stated as a theorem, it wouldn't hurt to cite it.

It's true that the fact that $|f_n(n) - f(n)| = 1$ holds for all $n$ prevents uniform convergence. For if $(f_n)$ converged uniformly, there would be some $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, the inequality $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < 1$ would hold for all $n \geq N$ and all $x$, and yet it doesn't (as you have noted by putting $n=x=N$).